# Is there an intuitive relationship between linear equations and the columnar vectors that represent the linear combination that is the same system?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a system like
$$
y=2x+4 \\
y=-x
$$
and you draw the lines out on a plane, and then you take the augmented matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2&1&4\\   
 1&1&0     
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you draw out its columnar vectors, there doesn’t appear to be some intuitive relationship between the two. I get that you’re deriving some *other set* of conditions (as part of the matrix) that you’re then solving, but *is* there some intuitive, easy-to-grasp spatial relationship between the arrangement of those vectors in space and the original lines?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be useful, but in that exact system $$\begin{cases}
      -2x + y = 4\\
      x + y = 0
    \end{cases}\,$$
each equation represents a line, and the vector $(-2,1)$ is orthogonal to the line that represents the first equation, and $(1,1)$ is orthogonal to the line that represents the second equation. If you want a relationship between terms of the same column, I would say that there isn't any relation, as far as I know. The only geometrical approach would be between coefficients of the same equation, which in this case represent orthogonal vectors. I hope it helped.